# 2 simple questions about Banach space

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Given that X is a normed space. Let $S=\left \{ x \in X : \left \| x \right \|=1 \right \}$.

Prove that $X$ is a Banach space iff every Cauchy sequence $\left\{x_{n}\right\}$ in $S$, there is  $x$ such that $x_{n} \rightarrow x$.

Let $x_{n}$ be a sequence in $X$ such that $ \forall f\in X^*, \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} f(x_{n})=f(x)$ for some $x \in X$. Is it always true that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} x_{n}=x$?

Comment: The second question: no.  Weak convergence is not the same as norm convergence.  Not even on the unit sphere in $L^\infty$, for example.

Answer (score 2):

For first point, use that any vector in a pre-Banach space can be normalized to unity.

Comment: Nam: this is a good hint.  If you work on it, and can't do it, ask for more.

Comment: I think the _only if_ part is trivial because it is done by the definition of Banach space. However, I do not write the _if part_. Can you give me a hand?